# Не всегда получаю id div'а

Tags: javascript, html

В прошлом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1180118/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-id-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8-js) мне помогли с получением `id` `div`. Но в некоторых дивах есть `img` с шахматными фигурами и оттуда не получаю `id` клетки. Помогите пофиксить это.

### Код

```js
const handleClick = event => {
  const id = event.target.id
  if (id) {
    console.log(id)
  }
}



function build_chess() {

    var row, column;
    var square;
    var container = document.getElementById("container");

    for (row = 0; row < 8; ++row) {
        for (column = 0; column < 8; ++column) {
            square = document.createElement("div");
            square.id = String(row) + String(column);
            if ((row + column) % 2 == 0) {
                square.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            } else {
                square.style.backgroundColor = "brown";
            }
            square.classList.add("square");
            switch (row) {
                case 0:
                    switch (column) {
                        case 0:
                        case 7:
                            square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/lad_black.png'></img>";
                            break;
                        case 1:
                        case 6:
                            square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/kon_black.png'></img>";
                            break;
                        case 2:
                        case 5:
                            square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/slon_black.png'></img>";
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/ferz_black.png'></img>";
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/king_black.png'></img>";
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/pesh_black.png'></img>";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/pesh_white.png'></img>";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    switch (column) {
                        case 0:
                        case 7:
                            square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/lad_white.png'></img>";
                            break;
                        case 1:
                        case 6:
                            square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/kon_white.png'></img>";
                            break;
                        case 2:
                        case 5:
                            square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/slon_white.png'></img>";
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/ferz_white.png'></img>";
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/king_white.png'></img>";
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            container.appendChild(square);
        }
    }
}





build_chess()
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", handleClick)
```

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

@media (min-width: 570px) {
    #container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 400px;
        border: 12px solid black;
        border-radius: 6px;
        height: 400px;
        transform: scale(1.5);
    }

    .square {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
    }
    .square img{
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 570px) {
    #container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 200px;
        border: 6px solid black;
        border-radius: 3px;
        height: 200px;
        transform: scale(1.7);
    }

    .square {
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
    }
    .square img{
        height: 25px;
        width: 25px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Шахматная доска</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container"></div>

    <script src="js.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для это добавьте метод [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest):

```js
const handleClick = event => {
  const id = event.target.closest('div.square').id
  if (id) {
    console.log(id)
  }
}

function build_chess() {
  var row, column;
  var square;
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  for (row = 0; row < 8; ++row) {
    for (column = 0; column < 8; ++column) {
      square = document.createElement("div");
      square.id = String(row) + String(column);
      if ((row + column) % 2 == 0) {
        square.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      } else {
        square.style.backgroundColor = "brown";
      }
      square.classList.add("square");
      switch (row) {
        case 0:
          switch (column) {
            case 0:
            case 7:
              square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/lad_black.png'></img>";
              break;
            case 1:
            case 6:
              square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/kon_black.png'></img>";
              break;
            case 2:
            case 5:
              square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/slon_black.png'></img>";
              break;
            case 3:
              square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/ferz_black.png'></img>";
              break;
            case 4:
              square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/king_black.png'></img>";
              break;
          }
          break;
        case 1:
          square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/pesh_black.png'></img>";
          break;
        case 6:
          square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/pesh_white.png'></img>";
          break;
        case 7:
          switch (column) {
            case 0:
            case 7:
              square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/lad_white.png'></img>";
              break;
            case 1:
            case 6:
              square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/kon_white.png'></img>";
              break;
            case 2:
            case 5:
              square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/slon_white.png'></img>";
              break;
            case 3:
              square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/ferz_white.png'></img>";
              break;
            case 4:
              square.innerHTML = "<img src='content/king_white.png'></img>";
              break;
          }
          break;
      }
      container.appendChild(square);
    }
  }
}
build_chess()
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", handleClick)
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

@media (min-width: 570px) {
  #container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 400px;
    border: 12px solid black;
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 400px;
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  .square {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }
  .square img {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 570px) {
  #container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 200px;
    border: 6px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 200px;
    transform: scale(1.7);
  }
  .square {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
  }
  .square img {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Шахматная доска</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Не знаю, будет ли тебе интересно сделать новый ответ, где будет настоящая [шахматная аннотация](https://chesswood.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/chessboard-with-numbers-2.jpg) для id. **Первый ряд снизу**  a1; b1; c1 ...  8 ряд сверху a8;b8;c8